# kernel and cokernel of corestriction map in cohomology of a profinite group

Tags: homological-algebra, group-cohomology, topological-groups, profinite-groups, galois-cohomology

Let $G$ be a profinite group, $N$ a normal open subgroup and $A$ a discrete $G$-module. We have a corestriction map $cor: H^1(N, A)_{G/N} \to H^1(G, A)$. Are there any results on the kernel and cokernel of this map? For example, does this map fit into an exact sequence?

Comment: There is a spectral sequence by Tate. This is explained in Cohomology of Number Fields.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisWuthrich. Yes, the Tate spectral sequence is somewhat relevant

Comment: prop. 3.3.11 in Cohomology of Number Fields proves that $cor$ is an isomorphism if $cd_p(G)=1$